# loop binary image pixel

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

i have this image with two people in it. it is binary image only contains black and white pixels.

first i want to loop over all the pixels and find white pixels in the image.

than what i want to do is that i want to find [x,y] for the one certain white pixel.

after that i want to use that particular[x,y] in the image which is for the white pixel in the image.

using that co-ordinate of [x,y] i want to convert neighbouring black pixels into white pixels. not whole image tho.

i wanted to post image here but i cant post it unfortunately.  i hope my question is understandable now. in the below image you can see the edges.

say for example the edge of the nose i find that with loop using [x,y] and than turn all neighbouring black pixels into white pixels.

[This is the binary image](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/8206/helloq.jpg)

Comment: Rewrite the whole question, it is not understandable.

Comment: Include links to the images you want to show.

Comment: Try writing a mock piece of code so we can better understand what you are after.

Comment: i included the link to image now. @mmgp

Answer (score 3):

The operation described is called dilation, from Mathematical Morphology. You can either use, for example, `scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation` or implement your own.

Here are the two forms to do it (one is a trivial implementation), and you can check the resulting images are identical:

```
import sys
import numpy
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage

img = Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('L') # Input is supposed to the binary.
width, height = img.size
img = img.point(lambda x: 255 if x > 40 else 0) # "Ignore" the JPEG artifacts.

# Dilation
im = numpy.array(img)
im = ndimage.binary_dilation(im, structure=((0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0)))
im = im.view(numpy.uint8) * 255
Image.fromarray(im).save(sys.argv[2])

# "Other operation"
im = numpy.array(img)
white_pixels = numpy.dstack(numpy.nonzero(im != 0))[0]
for y, x in white_pixels:
    for dy, dx in ((-1,0),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,0)):
        py, px = dy + y, dx + x
        if py >= 0 and px >= 0 and py < height and px < width:
            im[py, px] = 255
Image.fromarray(im).save(sys.argv[3])
```

Comment: +1 for your psychic powers in figuring out what the OP was after!

Comment: one question if image is in binary why is there line that converts image into grayscale ? sorry if that is dumb question but i was confused about it ?

Comment: It is your image, not mine. You saved it using JPEG, which will very likely create these kind of artifacts. Save it in a lossless format (JPEG2000 doesn't count).

Comment: yeh i changed the format to png. the code you gave is thickening  the edges for whole image. i just want to do for the middle part of the face not the whole pic. i tried playing around with code but i cant figure out :(  @mmgp

Comment: In the loop `for y, x in white_pixels` you need some other information to determine whether to dilate the point or not. The process is the same, but you have to somehow define where is the middle part of the face.